# What is the symbolism of Labyrinth in Grisaia no Meikyuu?

Tags: symbolism, grisaia

The first VN/season deals with the fruit of Grisaia, the sins (or sorrow) of the girls.

[Is the Fruit of Grisaia an actual fruit?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3139/is-the-fruit-of-grisaia-an-actual-fruit)

Now, what is *Labyrinth* in the title of the second game supposed to mean?

Comment: I can't give an authoritative answer as I don't think the creators have ever confirmed this, but having read the VNs I believe the meanings of the two sequel's titles are pretty obvious - labyrinth I think refers to Yuuji's past and the plots/conspiracies that have developed around him, which become's critical in the third VN, the eden of grisaia. The meaning of 'eden' in the third VN is very straightforward but is also a spoiler.

Comment: @Bron yes, the Eden in Grisaia no Rakuen is very straightforward... also, can you move your comment into an answer? it is good enough.